# Uncaught syntax error:unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a string value to a basic javascript function and get the following error

> *Uncaught syntax error:unexpected token illegal*

This is the code behind

```
string value = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22"
<input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' onClick='saveViewItemTester("+value+")'
```

and this is the function
This is the javascript

```
function saveViewItemTester(prod) {
    alert(prod);
}
```

Help with resolving this little issue if possible

kind regards

Comment: How are you mixing C# and Javascript?

Comment: onClick supposed to be `onclick`

Comment: Where are you writing this line? string value = "... . In Js or code behind? Please edit your question and write C# and Javascript code seperatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- no types in javascript
- value is reserved word, don't use it as variable name
- input tag isn't closed
- no need to "+" the variable
- use ; in javascript

Use this in between the head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22";

function saveViewItemTester(prod) {
  alert(prod);
}
</script>
```

Use this between the body tags:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="butSimulate" onClick="saveViewItemTester(test)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a typeless language. If you want a string, just assign it:

```
 value = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in case value is C# code

```
 <input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' 
        onClick='saveViewItemTester('<%=value%>')'/>
```

else use as

```
   var value = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22";
   <input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' 
        onClick='saveViewItemTester('+ value +')'/>
```

Comment: I reckon you'd loose the `+` signs?

Answer (score 1):

just convert `"` to `'` on your function call, as:

```
<input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' onClick='saveViewItemTester('+value+')'/>
```

Comment: I am expecting `"7dim-034/hallo/01:22"` is the value you want to pass from client side only.

Answer (score 1):

for C#, `string value = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22"`

```
<input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' 
    onClick='saveViewItemTester("<%=value%>")'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="butSimulate" onclick="saveViewItemTester('7dim-034/hallo/01:22')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-factor your code as follows-

**C# code-**

```
 public string value = "7dim-034/hallo/01:22";
```

**Javascript Code-**

```
<input type = 'button' value='submit' id='butSimulate' onclick='saveViewItemTester("<%=value%>")'/>

function saveViewItemTester(prod) {
    alert(prod);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can pass the value without "+" and declaring without String, just var.
for example:

```
var value = "hola";

<input type="button" value="submit" id="butSimulate" onclick="saveViewItemTester(value)"/>
```